# when i use an 'or' in my if statement it does work properly in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

When I use an 'or' in my if statement it takes what's in the bottom if statement

```
@client.command()
async def png(ctx, *, arg):
    if(arg == 'mixbox' or 'item box'):
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File('mixbox.png'))
    elif(arg == 'pack'):
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File('pack.png'))
```

when I type **!png item box** it gives a png of an item box. when I type **!png pack** it still give the same png item box.

but if I change the code to this:

```
@client.command()
async def png(ctx, *, arg):
    if(arg == 'mixbox'):
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File('mixbox.png'))
    elif(arg == 'item box'):
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File('mixbox.png'))
    elif(arg == 'pack'):
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File('pack.png'))
```

it works fine. Do I just do it this way or is there a way to make it work?
(I'm a beginner so there might be a simple answer that I don't know)

Comment: `or` does not work that way. you're looking for `arg == 'mixbox' or arg == 'item box'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `or` operator, you need to specify it for both conditions. Here you go, this should work:

```py
@client.command()
async def png(ctx, *, arg):
    if(arg == 'mixbox' or arg == 'item box'):
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File('mixbox.png'))
    elif(arg == 'pack'):
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File('pack.png'))
```